# Equivalent of "typename", to indicate that a dependant name is indeed a 'template template parameter'

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, dependent-name

We reduced a portion of code we cannot find the right syntax for to a minimal example.

Let's assume the following definitions (worry not about the "why" ;)

```
template <class>
class Element
{};

template <template <class> class>
class Client
{};

template <class>
struct TemplatedProvider
{
    template <class T>
    using element_template = Element<T>;
};
```

Now, with C++11 onward, we can use either a class template or a type alias template to instantiate the `Client` template. The following function compiles just fine:

```
void fun()
{
    Client<Provider::element_template> client;
    Client<TemplatedProvider<int>::element_template> clientBis;
}
```

But we cannot find the proper syntax in the following case, when the template argument given to `Client` is a dependent name:

```
template <class T>
void templatedFun()
{
    Client<TemplatedProvider<T>::element_template> client;
}
```

Clang (tested with 3.6) is emitting the following compilation error:

```
template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
```

Can we fix this syntax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `template` keyword:

```
template <class T>
void templatedFun()
{
    Client<TemplatedProvider<T>::template element_template> client;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for detailed discussion on the `template` and `typename` keywords.

Answer (score 9):

It has to be:

```
template <class T>
void templatedFun()
{
    Client<TemplatedProvider<T>::template element_template> client;
}
```